# struts2 jquery autocomplete onselect call a javascript function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, struts2, jquery-autocomplete

Am working with a java web application that was using struts2 features.
Am having one struts2 jquery autocomplete in one UI. And when loading this, am having a listKey and listValue for this autocomplete field.

What i need is when onselect work on this i need to get the id of the selected item.

For this its providing `onSelectTopics='somefunction-name'`. I used this functionality, but its not working. And i can't get the id using this . 
What i tried so far is as follws:

```
<sj:autocompleter list="%{metrics}" id="autoCompleterSearch" 
                                            listValue="value"
                                            listKey="id"
                                            cssStyle="font-size: 10px;" 
                                            onSelectTopics="autocompleteSelect" key="true"></sj:autocompleter> 
$.subscribe('autocompleteSelect', function(event, data) {
    var ui = event.originalEvent.ui;
        var message = ui.item.value;
        if(ui.item.key) {
            message = '( '+ ui.item.key +' ) '+message;
        }
            $('#topics').html('<b>'+message+'</b>');
        });
```

Can anyone help me to solve this.?

Comment: whats the problem coming?? better use firebug with Mozilla to see whats the problem coming in executing your code

Comment: Please add alert(event.toSource()) before var ui = event.originalEvent.ui; and post the response. BTW, sj:autocompleter is buggy and does not work as expected. I would use sj:select with autocomplete="on"